# Javascript Regex - must starts with letters can only have one occurrence of special character

Tags: javascript, regex, find-occurrences

I am new to Regular Expressions and trying to create one for a specific requirement per below :

1. Must starts with letters a-Z or A-Z
2. Can contain numbers 0-9
3. Can contain only allowed special characters i.e. @.-'
4. Only one occurrence of above special characters is allowed i.e. test9@my.com or new-test10@me.com is valid but test5@new@com is invalid

I have tried below code but not able to fulfill all requirements -

```
var myregex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9@.\-'])*$/;
if(!myregex.test(userIdVal)){
    alert('invalid');
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not trying to validate email addresses. This is a custom validation for usernames. I have used JQuery validation framework for email validation.

Comment: If you want to allow each of the special characters `[@'.-]` only once, try by capturing inside a lookahead and check for backreference to captured one: [`/^[a-z](?!.*?([@'.-]).*?\1)[a-z\d@'.-]*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/ToxlsQ/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing away with regex when checking that the `@.-'` chars are used only once:

```
var myregex, specialCharOccurrences, i, key;

// Test to see that only the allowed characters are used
myregex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9@.\-'])*$/;
if(!myregex.test(userIdVal)){
    alert('invalid');

// Test for multiple occurrences of the special characters
// a) create object in which the number of occurrences of the special characters are stored
specialCharOccurrences = {
    "@": 0,
    ".": 0,
    "-": 0,
    "'": 0
};

// b) count the number of occurrences. If the # is greater than 1, send an alert.
for (i = 0; i < userIdVal.length; i++) {
    if (/[@.\-']/.test(userIdVal[i])) specialCharOccurrences[userIdVal[i]]++;
    if (specialCharOccurrences[userIdVal[i]] > 1) alert("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Not only does this not validate the input for 3 requirements, only 2, but you split the 2 requirements into 1 + (length of string)  regexes. For  a non-regex solution, this is nothing but several regexes. Very slow and hard to read, with loops and counters. Meanwhile, it can be done with a single line regex test...

Answer (score 2):

I think this works, just sandwich a special between the others.

`^(?=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*[@.'-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Explained

```
 ^ 
 (?= [a-zA-Z] )        # A char is in this string and starts with
 [a-zA-Z0-9]*          # Optional alnums
 [@.'-]?               # Optional single special
 [a-zA-Z0-9]*          # Optional alnums
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `var myregex = /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*[@\.-][a-zA-Z\d]*$/`

It may not look nice and tidy but hey, it's a regexp :>